# global variable lost value from one action to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a global variable de type string (erreurUtilisateurExist) and changing its value from one action to another with the objective of passing its content through a ViewBag to the View. However, it is passed as null. Can someone tell me where is my error please, must be something simple I can not see. Sorry somethings are in French.

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{

    string erreurUtilisateurExist = "";        

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ErreurUtilisateurExist = erreurUtilisateurExist;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Utilisateur utilisateur)
    {
        bool NotinDB = Utilisateur.creer(utilisateur);

        if (NotInDB)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(utilisateur.Email, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            erreurUtilisateurExist = "There is a user already using this address";
            return View("Create");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its not a 'global' variable. Its initialized in controller. Each time a request is made, a new instance of your controller created (the web is stateless). You need to persist the value somewhere (e.g. a database, `Session` etc)

Comment: The what you should be doing is adding a `ModelState` error and returning the view so that the error is displayed

Comment: Not sure if I understand very well, but I will verify this. Thanks

Comment: You mean somethng like if(modelState.IsValid)...

Comment: In this particular case, there is an exception created because the database has the Email as UNIQUE

Comment: In your `else` block, `ModelState.AddModelError("", "There is a user already using this address"); return View(utilisateur);` and it will be displayed in your `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

Comment: And you can also use a `[Remote]` attribute for client side validation - [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx)

Comment: Stephen that worked perfect, could you do it in the other section where I can rate you please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web is stateless, and each time a request is made, a new instance of you controller, and therefore a new instance of `erreurUtilisateurExist` variable is created (its value is not persisted).

In you case, the correct approach is to add a `ModelState` error and return the view so that it is displayed to the user. Change you controller code to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Utilisateur utilisateur)
{
    if (!ModelStateIsValid)
    {
        return View(utilisateur);
    }
    bool NotinDB = Utilisateur.creer(utilisateur);
    if (NotInDB)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(utilisateur.Email, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "There is a user already using this address");
        return View(utilisateur);
    }
}
```

and the error message will be displayed in the element generated by your `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in the view.

If you want to display the error associated with a specific property, then use (say)

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "There is a user already using this address");
```

which will be displayed in the placeholder defined by

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
```

You can also use the `[Remote]` attribute to give you client side validation - refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx)